# oVirt - Running VMs into a Subnet

Tags: linux, openvswitch, ovirt

I am trying to run VMs (and Pools) into a NAT. To reach this target I have:

- created a new Network in the Cluster;
- checked "Create on external provider" check box;
- selected ovirt-provider-ovn;
- entered (in the "Subnet" tab) Name, CIDR, gateway and DNS.
- assigned the network to a VM

When I run the VM, it is correctly getting the subnet IP, but it is completely isolated. Cannot either ping the Gateway or the DNS server.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per RHV 4.3 documentation, you can only create isolated OVN networks through oVirt API or routed OVN networks through Neutron API. Source NAT is not (yet) implemented

> If you add Open Virtual Network (OVN) (ovirt-provider-ovn) as an external network provider, multiple subnets can be connected to each other by routers. To manage these routers, you can use the OpenStack Networking API v2.0. Please note, however, that ovirt-provider-ovn has a limitation: Source NAT (enable_snat in the OpenStack API) is not implemented.

source: https://red.ht/33V7ObK

Comment: Thank you Stefano. So, no way to have a Source NAT for VMs in oVirt? Maybe using external services/devices/hardware?

Comment: Just provision a VyOS vm between OVN network and the logical network and then simply configure source NAT https://vyos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nat.html It won't be strictly SDN but it will works.